Testing sitemap, rich results, etc. on my dev slot
How can I set things up so that I can access my dev slot with the Google developer console, but in a way that Google will not index the page.
I can't use robots.txt because we push our app to production by swapping the dev and production slots. So any file in dev then goes to production.
We are using Azure App Services.
Note: I'm not sure if this is an Azure App Services question (swap slots) or a robots.txt question. So I've also asked it on StackOverflow. I'll copy any answer from there to here.
